# Missing first letter at first index of an array using vector in c++

Tags: c++

Good day. I am new in c++ programming and I've faced a small problem...

Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;

    vector<string> name_array;
    bool add_more = true;
    cout<<endl<<"Add name: ";
    while(true) {
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);
        name_array.push_back(name);
        cout<<"Add more name? Yes(1) No(0): ";
        cin>>add_more;
        if(add_more == false)
            break; 
        else {
            cout<<endl<<"Add name: ";
        }
    }
    cout<<"name list: "<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < name_array.size(); i++) {
        cout<<name_array[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Add name: John
Add more goods? Yes(1) No(0): 0
name list:
ohn //missing first letter
```

As we can see, the user inputted the name 'John' but the result is 'ohn'. How to fix that issue? I don't have any idea what happen there why the first letter is missing.

Comment: the problem in line `cin.ignore();`

Comment: When I remove the `cin.ignore()` the `getline(cin, name);` will skip in the next loop.

Comment: You can fix that by changing code to `cin.ignore(ignore++ ? 1 : 0);` and adding `int ignore = 0;` before loop, but this is not a good idea. Better to get rid of ignore() and use another approach

Comment: Thanks. Can you post your answer so I can accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: I can :-) - just added. But avoid this in serious development, this is very artificial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in line.

```
cin.ignore();
```

You can simply fix that by changing a fragment of code to:

```
int ignore = 0;
while(true) {
    cin.ignore(ignore++ ? 1 : 0);
    getline(cin, name);
```

So you use it only once.

However this is not the best idea. Consider another approach to get rid of ignore() and use `cin >>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) for `cin.ignore()`. With no arguments, it will ignore the first character read from a file, which is why your output `ohn` is missing the first character, `J`.

Answer (score 0):

> In both the above codes, the output is not printed as desired. Reason
>   to this is an occupied Buffer. The “\n” character goes remains there
>   in buffer and read as next input.

and then

> Using “ cin >> ws ” : Typing “cin>>ws” after “cin” statement tells the
>   compiler to ignore buffer and also to discard all the whitespaces
>   before the actual content of string or character array.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clearing-the-input-buffer-in-cc/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;

    vector<string> name_array;
    bool add_more = true;
    cout<<endl<<"Add name: ";
    while(true) {
        getline(cin, name);
        name_array.push_back(name);
        cout<<"Add more name? Yes(1) No(0): ";
        cin>>add_more>>ws;
        if(add_more == false)
            break; 
        else {
            cout<<endl<<"Add name: ";
        }
    }
    cout<<"name list: "<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < name_array.size(); i++) {
        cout<<name_array[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but adding `ws` seems not working for some reason.  it will not allow me to input another name again.

Answer (score 0):

I initially proposed to use `cin >> name;` instead of `getline(cin, name);` but it does not work with multi-word names.

You can use what Anatoliy R suggested but extra variable is not needed if you move `cin.ignore` to the end of the loop:

```
string name;
vector<string> name_array;
bool add_more;
while (true) {
    cout << "Add name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    name_array.push_back(name);
    cout << "Add more name? Yes(1) No(0): ";
    cin >> add_more;
    if (!add_more)
        break;
    cin.ignore(); // skip EOL left after `cin>>add_more`
}
cout << "\nName list:" << endl;
for (auto n : name_array) {
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Or even simpler, you can avoid `cin >>` and second question at all:

```
string name;
vector<string> name_array;
while (true) {
    cout << "Add name (empty string to stop): ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name.size() == 0)
        break;
    name_array.push_back(name);
}
cout << "\nName list:" << endl;
for (auto n : name_array) {
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: if i use `cin>>name;` instead of `getline(cin, name);` this will work only if no white space on the string. for example if i add a name `'mak mak'`...

Comment: @NorynBasaya Ah, now I understood. I've updated the answer with other idea.